# How do I get AWS Fargate to send production.log to Cloudwatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

When I run Rails in AWS Fargate, I can log to Cloudwatch without an issue. The log you see in Cloudwatch, is the `rails server` log. In production you won't see the errors for production. However in `production.log` file you can see the errors. How do I get AWS Fargate to log production.log to Cloudwatch?

Comment: How is your `config/environments/production.rb` setting the `config.logger`?

Comment: @ErvalhouS `if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?`

Then it sets `config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)`. Right now I am not setting that env. And nothing else is setting `config.logger`

Comment: Yeah, for cloudwatch to see your logs it needs to output into STDOUT

Comment: Oh that's perfect! I just turned on `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` and it set it to STDOUT. Thanks so much @ErvalhouS!

Comment: Humbly suggest @EvalhousS post his answer, for proper attribution and votes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments above, I just realized that if you set `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` Cloudwatch can then see STDOUT. It works and I can now see my errors, so I can debug.